# R commander on MAC does not start in R v.4.0.3

Tags: r, r-commander

After updating my Os to BigSur 11.2 my R commander does not start at all.
In R window, after typing library(Rcmdr) R freezes with this screen.
I have my XQuartz updated to 2.7.11, Rcmdr is the latest.[freezes either on loading package sandwitch... or in mac terminal: "lattice theme set by effectsTheme() See?effectsTheme for details."](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H9gQK.jpg)
I don't know how to repair it so that Rcmdr works again.
Thank you for your help:)

Answer (score 0):

Try to install XQuartz version pre-release:
XQuartz 2.8.0_beta3 - 2021-02-01 - Pre-Release

https://www.xquartz.org/releases/index.html